# How much absoluteness holds between a Grothendieck universe and $V$?

Tags: set-theory

Using a fixed Grothendieck universe $\mathcal{U}$, assuming $\mathbb{N} \in \mathcal{U}$, we can define $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{U}}_c$ as the category of all countable $\mathcal{U}$-sets and functions between them, making $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{U}}_c$ locally $\mathcal{U}$-small. And we can also define the class counterpart $\mathbf{Set}_c$ as the category of all countable sets and functions between them. Then I came up with a question: Is $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{U}}_c$ really analogous to $\mathbf{Set}_c$? We are considering $V$-countable $\mathcal{U}$-sets, not the sets which $\mathcal{U}$ says countable. But this is not a problem, since for a $\mathcal{U}$-set $x$, $\mathbb{N}^{x} \in \mathcal{U}$, so there are no "hidden" functions, thus "$x$ is countable" is absolute between $V$ and $\mathcal{U}$. Are there some other interesting properties which is absolute between $V$ and $\mathcal{U}$?

Comment: Isn't a Grothendieck universe basically a transitive model of ZFC (- infinity, although not in your case) which knows the true power sets?

Comment: In other words, in terms of set theory, a Grothendieck universe (with $\mathbf N$) is exactly $V_{\kappa}$ for a strongly inaccessible $\kappa$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sufficient condition for absoluteness between a Grothendieck universe and the whole universe is that the property in question can be expressed by a set-theoretic formula in which every quantifier is *bounded*, i.e., of the form $\forall x\in t$ or $\exists x\in t$, where the bound $t$  is not allowed to mention $x$ (to avoid cheats like $\exists x\in\{x\}$) but is allowed to use the power-set operation. In addition to the "set of functions" $A^B$ as in the question, this would include, for example, the property of being a cardinal number.

(This absoluteness doesn't require the full strength of "Grothendieck  universe". It works for $V_\lambda$ whenever $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal.)